# It's occure when i run flutter doctor in CMD also i have latest version of flutter ,dart and andriod studio with plugins

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.22.0-12.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1397], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 1.22.0-12.1.pre at C:\src\flutter
• Framework revision 8b3760638a (2 weeks ago), 2020-09-15 17:47:13 -0700
• Engine revision 4654fc6cf6
• Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-110.3.beta)

[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
X Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to that location.
You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 50.0.1
• Dart plugin version 193.7547
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[!] Android Studio
• Android Studio at /path/to/android/studio
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
X android-studio-dir = /path/to/android/studio
X Android Studio not found at /path/to/android/studio
• Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
• Consider removing your android-studio-dir setting by running:
flutter config --android-studio-dir=

[√] VS Code (version 1.49.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\Saman\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.14.1

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Does what `flutter doctor` demand.